# Published project gives error SQLite.Interop.dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sqlite, desktop

I published a desktop application, but I'm having this the `DLLNotFoundException SQLite.Interop.dll` error. I've already searched in StackOverflow and in the web but noone of the solutions seems to work.

I'm using NET. Framework 4.5, Visual Studio 2015 and I've used the NuGet Package System.Data.SQLite.Core. Can someone help me? I really need to deploy the application.

Comment: For heaven's sake: _Which_ error?

Comment: @UweKeim DLLNotFoundException SQLite.Interop.dll

Answer (score 0):

There might be the following reasons possible behind this error:

1. Its possible that dll has some dependencies which are not registered in the same folder of your application.
2. If your application have x64 & x86 versions then make sure that the dll in both the folders matches.

Comment: I have checked the folder that is open in the visual studo and in the x64 and x86 the DLL is there. Can you help me more? Because still isn't working

Comment: Please match if the two dlls are same or not. i.e. copy the correct dll in both the folders and then try.

Comment: Still didn't managed to put it work. Trying another type of localDB